# Java: short min value -> Incompatible types: Required: short, Found: int

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation, short

I want to assign minimal value to `short` by using bit notation:

```
short s = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000;
```

But I get the message: **Incompatible types: Required: short, Found: int**

If I do the same for `int` value everything is ok:

```
int i = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000__0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

Where is the problem? Why does `0b1000_0000_0000_0000;` exceed `short int` range?

Answer (score 0):

`0b1000_0000_0000_0000` is an `int` literal. Therefore it represents the positive value `32768`, which is outside the range of the `short` type (`Short.MAX_VALUE` is `32767`).

On the other hand, `0b1000_0000_0000_0000__0000_0000_0000_0000` is also an `int` literal, so it can be assigned to an `int` variable. In this case, it represents a negative value - `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

If you want to assign to `s` the 16 least significant bits of `0b1000_0000_0000_0000`, use:

```
short s = (short)0b1000_0000_0000_0000;
```

Now `s` will contain `-32768` (which happens to be `Short.MIN_VALUE`).

Comment: Why do I have to use (short) in case `short s = (short)0b1000_0000_0000_0000` but with `0` as MSB I don't have to: `short s = 0b0000_0000_0000_0000` ?

Comment: @AppiDevo because in that case the int literal fits the range of the short type. For the same reason you can write `short s = 10000;`, but you cannot write `short s = 40000;`